# how to pass message from servlet to bootstrap modal

Tags: java, servlets, bootstrap-modal

Following is the servlet Part where I am getting the value of result. So I need to show this result in modal, please help in this case as I am new to this.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        Services service = new Services();

        String dsid = request.getParameter("dsid");
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String superadmin = request.getParameter("gridRadios");
        Boolean admin = null;
        if (superadmin.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
            admin = true;
        } else {
            admin = false;
        }
        String region = request.getParameter("region");

        String result = service.addAssociate(dsid, name, admin, region);

        // System.out.println("Result: " + result);
        response.getWriter().write(result);



    //I need to show value of 'result' in bootstrap modal


    }

}
```

This is my modal where I wanted to show value of result:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="success_msg" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
<div class="success">
  <div class="modal-dialog-success">
    <div class="col-xs-12 pade_none">
      <button type="button" class="close" onClick="closeConfirm();" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <div class="col-xs-12 pade_none">
           <p>Message to be shown over here</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 pad_none">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `response.getWriter().write(result)`
you need to forward the request to target page.

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher= request.getRequestDispatcher("/target.jsp");
request.setAttribute("result",result);

dispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

in your target.jsp

```
<!--omit bootstrap boilerplate-->
<!--use jstl-->
<c:out value="${requestScope.result}"></c:out>
```

or

```
<%
String result = (String)request.getAttribute("result");
%>


<!--omit bootstrap boilerplate-->
<%=result%>
```